# Light version of appcompat v4 to only use NotificationCompat

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-appcompat

I've seen that the android support library appcompat v4 takes actually about 1Mo on my final apk while I only use it to create Notifications with NotificationCompat.

I use a .jar of the library.

Since the source code is available (https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/tree/master/v4/java/android/support/v4) do you think it would help if I include the source code in my project instead of the .jar file? So the compiler would only include the necessary files.

Is it bad practice to do that?

Comment: You should focus on enabling ProGuard on your `release` builds. "I use a .jar of the library" -- AFAIK, none of the `support-v4` sub-artifacts are distributed as JARs.

Comment: Oh I don't know about that what is it? (Well i'ma google of course.) ;) -- Well. I have .jar library that was included with the code template back then if I remember.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html

Answer (score 0):

In my application i got the same problem as you: a huge jar file to use just a single class. I copied the sources of LocalBroadcastManager to my application and everything worked fine.

Comment: Yeah I wanted to do that but there are a lot of dependencies (like the NotificationCompat also import Views and other classes that are defined in the library) so it's not as easy as copying the corresponding file.. How did you do? Didn't your code import plenty of other classes from the library?

Comment: Actually not import, but use them.